# conversion of charsequence to String

Tags: android

I want to convert a charsequence to String value,I  use the following code for that

```
   string passwordTxtValue;
   passwordTxtValue = passwordTxt.getText().toString();
      System.out.println(""+passwordTxtValue);
```

But i am not getting the value,how can i resolve this.

Comment: what are you getting instead?

Comment: It returning a null value

Comment: try "Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, passwordTxt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();" What does that show?

Comment: Is `passwordTxt` is your editText?? EveryThing is right but instead of using SYSO() try to print it in LogCat. `Log.i("Any Value",passwordTxtValue)` Like this.

Comment: you might want to check how is the passwordTxt initialized. and when the above code is executed does it have any content.

Comment: the toast showing the right answer

Comment: That is why. In android SYSO is not showing in console as you see in java programming. So Like SYSO in java is same like Log.i(String, String);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Android System.out.println()` gets redirected to LogCat and printed using Log.i(). In java you have `System.out.println()` instead of that you can use [Android Log class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) in Android for the same purpose. And you can see the output in the Logcat. And one upperhand to see in the Logcat is you can get Stack Traces of any uncaught Exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Your value get converted correctly, but the java method println() won't work in Android